# How do I join string together in a list

Tags: python, string, list, split, append

```
gene=[]
x=1
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/abc.txt'
file = open(path,'r').readlines()

for i in file[x]:
  i.split('\t')[0]
  gene.append(i)
  x+=1

print(gene)
```

my output is

```
['A', 'H', 'Y', '3', '9', '2', '7', '8', '\t', '1', '4', '5', '.', '5', '4', '4', '\t', '1', '3', '5', '.', '2', '4', '\t', '5', '6', '.', '5', '1', '3', '8']
```

but i want it to split at '/t', taking  the first element in the list which is AHY392978 and append it into the list gene

```
['AHY39278', 'AHY39278']
```

any idea how to join the elements together?

Comment: Please provide an [mre]

Comment: `i.split('\t')[0]` does nothing…

Comment: You're only looping through the second line of the file character by character with `file[x]`. `x+=1` does nothing, as it's never used again afterwards.

Comment: Looks to me like you can skip that entire loop, and just use `file` as is. That's already a list of each individual line in the file.

Comment: @Andreas  i have edited my question, hope you can reopen it

Comment: @deceze , in file, there are many rows and i want to read every row with for loop, any idea?

Comment: `with open(...) as f: gene = [l.split('\t')[0] for l in f]`…?

Comment: @deceze another question, i tried using values = [l.split('\t')[1] for l in f] to obtain the numerical values, between the gene ids AHY39278 etc, but it didn't work, may i know why?

Comment: and values = []

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your project:

```
string = ''
for(i in range len(gene)):
    string += gene[i]
```

you can get your data from string